# MediaElement repeat play

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to play a video file in mediaelement repeatedly, but when I try to play video again in the MediaEnded event MediaElement clears screen and screen is still clear for some little but appreciable time range. How to decrease this time range or dispose of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide the code for the MediaEnded-event? A bit looking for me resulted in this:

- [**How to: Repeat Media Playback**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741866%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [**Social.MSDN: Repeat MediaElement**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsphone7series/thread/6ba24a9c-d8ba-44f7-b09f-767cfa870d1b)

Perhaps one of these approaches works better?

I also found out that this is a known issue in Silverlight (don't know if this also relates to the WP7 version): [**Looping with Silverlight media element - a small delay at end of clip before it plays**](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574422/looping-with-silverlight-media-element-a-small-delay-at-end-of-clip-before-it-plays-again)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that it is bug in Silverlight.

Comment: For future questions: Solved with placing last frame of video on the page background. Thanks again.